# Call to Cipher.getInstance makes an ftp call

Tags: java, encryption, ftp

My application makes call to Cipher.getInstance so it can decrypt passwords.
In certain environments this is creating a problem because the Cipher.getInstance method ends up trying to make an FTP call which is hanging.

Does anyone know how to avoid this FTP call or prevent it hanging?

Here is the stacktrace.

```
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:370)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:231)
    java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:643)
    java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:590)
    sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:971)
    sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:931)
    sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1026)
    sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1012)
    sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.connect(FtpURLConnection.java:307)
    sun.net.www.protocol.ftp.FtpURLConnection.getInputStream(FtpURLConnection.java:406)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(URLJarFile.java:227)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(URLJarFile.java:84)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(JarFileFactory.java:128)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(JarURLConnection.java:136)
    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.getJarFile(JarURLConnection.java:103)
    javax.crypto.a$0.run(Unknown Source)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:420)
    javax.crypto.a.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.a.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.a.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.b.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.d.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.d.a(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.c(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.b(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What *"certain environments"* are those? Do you have some special JCE provider?

Comment: The environment we saw the problem is where the ports were locked down, but I don't have other relevant information. We don't have a special JCE provider (using IBM JDK).